# Creating multiple linked lists from one structure

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am working to create a program where I read in information from a file and assign the information between 4 linked lists.  I have create the following structure to represent the information.

```
struct ListStruct{
  int waitingTime;
  struct ListStruct *next;
};
```

My question is to do with these typedefs. While the first defines the structure, I am not sure what the second does.  It creates a pointer to the struct 'Patron', but does it being typedef'd imply anything that may allow me to easily move between 4 linked lists?  If so, what is an effective way to utilize this?

```
typedef struct ListStruct Patron; 
typedef Patron *ListHeadPtr;
```

Comment: I seriously advise *against* typedef-ing a pointer-type. The *only* logical reason for doing so is to avert the mis-typed multi-varaible declaration list. I.e. `int* p1, p2` as opposed to `intPtr p1, p2;`, and honestly even *that* is a lame reason to do so. Do not fear the asterisk. *Embrace them and learn to love them.* They're like a giant single-char-red-flag that screams "This is a pointer!". This becomes even more important for code-clarity when reading code with double-indirection (pointers-to-pointers). Everyone has preferences, but in-general hiding asterisks has no *concrete* benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does it being typedef'd imply anything that may allow me to easily
>   move between 4 linked lists?

No, it's just for convenience.

> If so, what is an effective way to utilize this?

You can now pass linked lists into functions, like so:

```
ListHeadPtr append(ListHeadPtr aList, ListHeadPtr anotherList) {
    ....
}
```

**Addendum**

To "cons" an element (i.e. insert it at the start of the list):

```
ListHeadPtr cons(int waitTime, ListHeadPtr list) {
    ListHeadPtr first = malloc(sizeof(Patron));
    if (first == NULL) {
        /* Take evasive action */
    }
    first->waitingTime = waitTime;
    first->next = list;
    return first;
}
```

Comment: When creating an item for one of the lists, how would I go about assigning it?  At the end of the createPatron function, how would i conclude it?  EG: ListHeadPtr = patronPtr (where patronPtr has been malloc'ed before)

Comment: Additionally, how would I be able to declare which list is being worked on?  Would I need an additional ListHeadPtr definition? For example ListHeadPtr list1;

Comment: "how would I be able to declare which list is being worked on?" Store it in a variable?

Comment: The (ListHeadPtr list), what is being sent to that?

Comment: The list you want to add an element to.

Comment: That list would be defined in the main?

Comment: It would be defined somewhere (it doesn't need to be main(): could be another function).

Comment: I guess my final question would be; would it be possible to first create a pointer to a patron using a function, then sending that pointer to the cons function you've defined above?  Or would it be best to call the cons and then if there is nothing there I create the first element?  What type would the 'list' be defined as?

Comment: The first time you call "cons", list should be equal to NULL.

Comment: Ah okay, I get that, however what data type would list be when I define it? EG would it be: ListHeadPtr = list?

Comment: You would define `list` like `ListHeadPtr list`.

Comment: EDIT: One more issue.  I cannot define the cons function with (int waitTime, ListHeadPtr list).  It must be sent like (ListHeadPtr list, Patron * toBeAdded)

Comment: Then modify it accordingly.

Comment: I create a separate function which returns a pointer which can be placed in the toBeAdded.  I have:

`Patron *patronPtr = malloc(sizeof(Patron)*(sizeof(Patron)));

  patronPtr->waitingTime = time;
  
  patronPtr->next = NULL;
  
  ListHeadPtr = patronPtr;
 
  return (patronPtr);`

However, I cannot get the 2nd last line of code to work, it shoots me an error saying: expected identifier or '(' before '=' token